# Pending POST Request - AngularJS to Laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel, post, file-upload

I am sending a simple post request from AngularJS to Laravel API containing a name and an image. The problem is when I submit the request, it becomes pending for a long time. I have checked the code but I do not think there's anything which causes the request to take that much time.

I am using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) and here's what I am doing in the Angular side:

```
    service.store = function(hotel){
      console.log('uploading..');
      return Upload.upload({
          url: 'api/hotels',
          method: 'POST',
          fields: hotel,
          file: [hotel.logo],
          fileFormDataName: 'file[]',
          headers:{
              'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'
          }
      }).success(function (response){
          console.log(response)
          service.result = response;
      }).error(function (response){
          service.errors = response;
      });
    };
```

and for the Laravel side:

```
try{
    $hotel = new Hotel;
    $hotel->name = $request->name;
    $hotel->booking_availability = 0;
    $hotel->save();
    $slug = str_slug($request->name, "-");
    $hotel->slug = $slug."-".$hotel->id;
    $hotel->save();
    if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
        $type = explode("/", $_FILES['file']['type'][0]); 
        $name = date_timestamp_get(date_create())  . "." . $type[1];

        $target = 'img/hotels/logo/original/'.$name;
        $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][0];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$target");

        $hotel->logo = $name;
        $hotel->logo_path = $target;
        $hotel->save();
    }

    return response()->json(['hotel' => $hotel], 200);
}catch(Exception $e){
    return response()->json(['error' => $e], 500);
}
```

What could be the possible error that takes such amount of time? How can I further debug this issue?
[image: Request Time Screenshot]

**EDIT:**

I tried using `gzip` to compress the content before sending the post request in order to reduce the time needed but nothing changed.